# many functions and many variables

Tags: python, class, oop

for the seek of simplicity I will only use three functions as follows. I need to evaluate the functions at first and later on use these results for other calculations. I would like to create an interface such that I only provide the value of input variable x and then easily calculate all the functions. I would like to use a class for this purpose. How can I do this with OOP?

```
def function1(x):
    y=x+2
    z= x-2
    return y,z

value1=function1(x)
def function2 (x):
    y1= value1[0] *10 # value1 can be replaced by function1(x)
    z1= value1[1] +5  # but the aim and it will work but i have so many functions
    return y1,z1
def main(x):
    print(f1(x),f2(x))

main(2)
```

Comment: which python version do you have ?

Comment: i use Python 3.8

Comment: check if my answer works for you now

Comment: Try improving the question by (1) dropping any unnecessary information and restructuring your question such that it is very clear at first sight. While answering I had to make some guesses. A well-presented question will not need any guess-work to understand what is needed.

Comment: You could say it like this: _I have say, 20 functions. For the sake of simplicity I will only use three functions as follows. I need to evaluate the functions at first and later on use these results for other calculations. I would like to create an interface such that I only provide the value of input variable x and then easily calculate all the functions. I would like to use a class for this purpose. How can I do this with OOP?_

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to do this :

```
def function1(x):
y=x+2
z= x-2
return y,z



def function2 (x):
v1,v2 = function1(x)
y1= v1 *10 
z1= v2 +5  
return y1,z1

def main(x):
print(function1(x),function2(x))

main(2)
```

---

This is how you can use them in a class :

```
class Functions :

def function1 : 
# ....

def function2 :
# ....
```

And you can use it in other page like this :

```
from page2 import Functions

Functions.function1(..)
Functions.function2(..)
```

Comment: same problem , it will raise the error "NameError: name 'x' is not defined"

Comment: wait , do you use "x" ? you dont have to do this , if you want to use "x" then you should do it inside the function , like i'll edit for you now , check it now please

Comment: thanks , but as i mentioned in the question that i have many functions and many variables , so function1 and function2 will be used many times in other functions, do you think class can be useful ?

Comment: @MhmdQadi in that case yes , it will make it better

Comment: can you please propose how this can be applied on the code?  thanks karam

Comment: @MhmdQadi i edited the answer to show you how

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

You could in principle create a class as follows and then use the functions to calculate what you want. If you want to access the evaluated results for `function_01(x)`, just use `f.values['function_01']`. I chose to use it like this so that you could dynamically save the results of all the methods (functions) and the `dict` keys would be self-explanatory.

- You can also directly evaluate any of the methods (`function_01,02,03`)
- Also, you could create some short aliases if you like using `enable_func_aliases = True` while instantiating the class object or later calling `create_func_aliases()` method.

```py
# implementation of class Functions
f = Functions(x=10, evaluate=True)
print(f)
print(f.values) # values is a dict
# To create short aliases for functions (methods)
f.create_func_aliases()
```

**Output**:

```sh
Functions( x: 10, evaluate: True )
{'function_01': (12, 8), 
'function_02': (143, 5, 243), 
'function_03': (2100, 0, 8)}
```

### Code: `class Functions`

```py
class Functions(object):

    def __init__(self, x=None, evaluate: bool=False, 
                 enable_func_aliases: bool=False):
        self.x = x
        self.evaluate = evaluate
        self.enable_func_aliases = enable_func_aliases
        self.values = dict()
        self._update()

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}( x: {}, evaluate: {} )'\
            .format(self.__class__.__name__, self.x, self.evaluate)

    def evaluate_functions(self):
        self.evaluate = True
        self._update_values()

    def _update(self):
        if self.evaluate:
            self.evaluate_functions()
        if self.enable_func_aliases:
            self.create_func_aliases()

    def _update_values(self):
        self.values.update({'function_01': self.function_01()})
        self.values.update({'function_02': self.function_02()})
        self.values.update({'function_03': self.function_03()})

    def create_func_aliases(self):
        self.enable_func_aliases = True
        self.f01 = self.function_01
        self.f02 = self.function_02
        self.f03 = self.function_03    

    def function_01(self, x=None):
        if x is None: x = self.x
        if x is not None:
            y = x + 2
            z = x - 2
            return (y, z)

    def function_02(self, x=None):
        if x is None: x = self.x
        if x is not None:
            y = x**2 + 4*x + 3
            z1 = x - 5
            z2 = y + 10*x
            return (y, z1, z2)

    def function_03(self, x=None):
        if x is None: x = self.x
        if x is not None:
            y1 = 10*x + 2*(x**3)
            y2 = x**3 - 10*(x**2)
            z = x - 2
            return (y1, y2, z)
```

Comment: @MhmdQadi Perhaps you were looking for something like this.

Comment: If this answer helped, please consider **`voting up`** and **`accepting`** (if applicable).

Comment: I did it, can you please do the same if you think my question was clear

Comment: Thank you. I left some comments. Please work on improving the clarity of the question. You may use my suggestions. A well structured question must not enforce any guess-work from the reader.

Answer (score 0):

`function2` can be simplified a little bit by unpacking the tuple from `function1` into two variables.

```
def function2(x):
    y, z = function1(x)
    return y * 10, z + 5
```

Comment: Thanks but i have more than 10 functions and they are interconnected, so every time i use function1 , i have to do the same, right ?

Comment: That's the best answer I can give without knowing what your functions do and do not have in common. You basically need to look for any pieces of repeated code and factor them out into their own functions.

Comment: Thank you luther for your time , your comment is helpful